# Is there a way to redirect from a Bash command directly to an S3 file object?

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Currently, I have Bash commands redirecting output to a log file, and then a separate CLI `aws s3 cp` call to copy the log file up to S3.

I was wondering if there's a way to redirect output straight to S3 without the extra command/step. I tried doing the `aws s3 cp` to a `https` url but that doesn't seem to work since urls are for currently existing files/objects on S3.

Comment: I believe it should be possible as kinesis is streaming to s3 so you should be able to write log file to s3 as it gets created. I am not sure the CLI has this options though, working with boto or nodeJS/npm you might have more possibilities - remember also that s3 charges per PUT requests, costing $0.005 for each 1k requests. when you run `aws s3 cp ....` its 1 request but if you stream you will have lot of requests

Answer (score 0):

I never tested it, but chech if it is reasonable:

`aws s3 cp <(/path/command arg1 arg2) s3://mybucket/mykey`

Here `/path/command arg1 arg2` is your "Bash commands redirecting output to a log file", but you can't redirect output, you need to leave it in the `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether its an overkill based on the gravity of your scenario, but using a [AWS File Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/WhatIsStorageGateway.html), you can put the files to a mounted disk and it will be synced automatically to S3.